# what's the meaning of "it prevents any guarantees from being made about the interface of exceptions"?

Tags: python, exception

from PEP 352:

> In Python 2.4 and before, any (classic) class can be raised as an
> exception. The plan for 2.5 was to allow new-style classes, but this
> makes the problem worse -- it would mean any class (or instance) can
> be raised! **This is a problem as it prevents any guarantees from being
> made about the interface of exceptions**.

so, I don't understand the meaning of "as it prevents any guarantees from being made about the interface of exceptions", can anyone help explain this?

Comment: Do you not understand the grammar of the sentence, or do you not know the meaning of particular words?

Comment: The interface means for example which methods and attributes that are available on the class. All exceptions should for example inherit the `with_traceback()` method from the base Exception class.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I understand the grammar of the sentence as well as the words in the sentence, what I'm struggling with is what assurance `Exception` makes and why it says "it prevents any guarantees"